# Examine continuity

Tags: real-analysis

When you're asked to 'examine continuity' of a function, is this the way to approach it:

> (a) $f(x)=|x|, \forall x \in\mathbb{R}$
>
> (b) $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x=0 \\ \sin\frac1x & x \ne 0\end{cases}  $
>
> (c) $f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/x} & x>0 \\ 0 & x\le 0\end{cases} $

(a): $\varepsilon > 0$. We need to find a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow ||x|-|x_0||<\varepsilon$.

We know that $||x|-|x_0|| \le |x-x_0| $, so we pick $\delta=\varepsilon$. Since $x_0$ was an arbitrary point from $\mathbb{R}$, we can conclude that $f(x)=|x|$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$.

(b):
$\sin\frac1x$ is continous over its domain, so we have $f(x)$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}_0$. Let's look at $x=0$: $f(0)=0$; $\lim_{x\to0+}\sin\frac1x = / $ and $\lim_{x\to0-}\sin\frac1x = / $. This means that $\lim_{x\to0} f(x) \ne f(0)  $ and therefor $f(x)$ is not continuous in $x=0$. Conclusion: $f(x)$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}_0$.

(c):
$e^{-1/x}$ is continuous over its domain, so we have $f(x)$ is continuous over $\{x>0\mid x \in\mathbb{R}\}$. The same argument can be applied to constant functions and therefor $f(x)$ will be continuous over $\mathbb{R}_0$. Let's look at $x=0$: $f(0)=0$; $\lim_{x\to0+}e^{-1/x} = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to0-}0 = 0$. Conclusion: $f(x)$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$.

Is there a more elegant way to examine continuity of piecewise functions?

Comment: b.  Define:  = /.

Comment: "does not exist"